# Error when loading data into PBI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've created a function from a query that fetches the weather forecast from darksy.net API.

Basically, I pass the latitude and longitude as a single parameter to the query and I get a weather forecat.

The parameter is entered as text in the form of "lat,long". Eg: Lisbon is ‎38.736946,-9.142685

Everything works fine, the data is loaded into Power Query. However, when hitting "Close and Apply" button I get the error:

[image]

It seems the URL is adding `E2%80%8E` before the parameter.

I tried 2 differente APIs (darksy.net and http://api.openweathermap.org) and the problem happens in both.

Why is this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Can we have a look at your query, please? The code you see in the [Advanced Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-query-overview#the-advanced-editor) window.

Comment: Sure, but now everything is ok again although I haven't changed anything in the query